# Deploy a go binary to cloud run that is not the top package

Tags: docker, go, google-cloud-run, buildpack

I have a go module containing several different "main" packages located in subdirectories `cmd/program1/program1.go`, `cmd/program2/program2.go`, and so on. I would like to deploy one of these as a webservice to Cloud Run.

The problem I am having is that the completely automated deploy command `gcloud run deploy --source .` seems to required that the program I am deploying has its own `go.mod` file located at `cmd/program1/go.mod`. However, my go.mod file is two levels up from there, and I can't easily change that because `program1` depends on several other Go packages in the module.

What I would like to do is submit the whole of my module to Cloud Build, and tell it that it should build and run package `cmd/program1`. How can I do that?

One approach that I am aware of is to create my own Dockerfile, build the docker image locally, and deploy that to Cloud Run. However, I do not want to run docker locally and would instead like to build everything in Cloud Build.

A second approach that I am aware of is to put a Dockerfile at the top level of my module, and submit that to Cloud Build. However, this means I can only deploy one of the programs in my module, since there will just be one top-level Dockerfile, and it will run some particular program from my module. Instead, I would like to have the flexibility to deploy several of the "main" packages in my module as separate Cloud Run services.

Is there a way, using the automated buildpack thing that Google has set up, to say to Cloud Build "hey please build such-and-such package as the main executable, and set that executable up as the thing to run on Cloud Run"?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the GOOGLE_ENTRYPOINT environment variable to specify the endpoint package:

```
gcloud builds submit . \
  --pack image=$(IMAGE),env=GOOGLE_ENTRYPOINT=./cmd/somepackage
```